# Merge two Skype chat archives

Tags: windows, skype, chat

I have two computers – both of them are Windows XP SP3 32-bit and running the **same** version of Skype and login with the **same** account.

How can I merge the chat histories of these two accounts into one and **continue using this account with all of my chat history**?

I don't want to export my chat for archive.

Comment: Found out that is impossible. I can only export my message to HTML or text. So this answer below is acceptable.

Comment: I just tried skyperios, but after I opened two different skype main.db, the "compare two databases" button is grey out, am I missing something or anyone have a clue?

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please do not ask questions in answer. Use comment instead (just like this one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I merge 2 chat history of this
>   two account into one?

If you're still using Skype 3.x, you can export the history to HTML (HTML files can be merged easily).

If you're using Skype 4.x, here's a tutorial how to **[Save Skype chat history](http://itarato.blogspot.com/2009/01/save-skype-chat-history.html)**. The output will be TXT files which you then can merge.

Comment: right, you want to get the same chat history on BOTH computers? this is not possible, however, if you're logged on at the same time on both computers with the same account (and only then) you will get the history for any chat on both machines, if you log out/turn off one machine, then only the other machine can keep the history.

Comment: My office PC is using Skype 3.8 and I cannot find a way to export my message to HTML format. Can you show me how?

Comment: @hvtuananh - open the chat you want to export and type the following command into the message window: /htmlhistory

Answer (score 8):

Use this open source tool: http://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/

It can compare and merge two main.db files, which contain all messages (among other things).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have chat history merged from multiple Skype installations until they are up and running all the time (in fact Skype syncs them while they are online).

And of course it is almost impossible to keep them always running in daily life.

AFAIK the only automated solution that merges Skype chat history is a Skype plugin [G-Recorder](http://www.g-recorder.com) which works well for me up to now.

Comment: you've posted the same link in answers to four different questions, three of them today.  some users may consider this spam.  if you are affiliated with the product, it's best to admit it, and make certain you only post it to questions to which it really applies.

Comment: Your software is unable to "sync" chats on multiple installations. It may be sending a copy to your email, but that is not what "sync" means. Even the FAQs say: The chat history will be merged in your email box.

Answer (score 1):

Last I looked Skype used unencrypted SQLite tables for conversation history. Some googling and a tool to merge SQLite tables may be able to help here.

Comment: I had (some time later ;)  the same idea about SQLite3. The ones interested in can get some hints from this [other answer](http://superuser.com/a/1011681/257269)... and do some gym with no need of 3rd party programs.

Answer (score 0):

Skype no longer exports chats as txt and html files. Even if it did, merging them would mean manual copy paste.
Latest versions of Skype use unencrypted SQLite database. Merging them manually can lead to serious problems. I came across a free open source tool which does this job effortlessly.
Copy the skype database folder (C:\Users\\AppData\Skype) from PC A to PC B. Install [Skyperious](http://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/), exit Skype completely, and then you can compare both databases (from PC B and that copied from PC A) and merge both ways (missing messages of B to A and vice-versa).