# How to read Skype .dat files

Tags: windows, skype

My .dat files are saved at C:\Users\enzo gladiadis\AppData\Roaming\Skype\ (myusernmame)\chatsync\8c

How do I open them? I have tried notepad but it is complete jibberish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this link](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-dat-file-word-54899.html) 
There are two detailed methods to do this:

- Change the file extension
- Use Word's "Open and Repair" feature

The steps for these methods is described in detail in the link given above
Hope this helps!

Comment: However, as they're dat files (also detailed in that article) you might still see gibberish. As it might e.g. be binary data. It would depend on what is actually being saved in those files.

Answer (score 0):

There are apps and script for that (some of them advised on this site).

**Edit:** It is good to start with https://secure.skype.com/en/data-export, and import the JSON into Skyperious.

- **Skyperious**, works with Sqlite.db files - http://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/
- NirSoft - **Skype log view**: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html
- https://pypi.org/project/skype-chatsync-reader/

Other questions on this subject here on SU, and on SO:

- [How can I read Skype log files (chatsync)?](https://superuser.com/questions/315486/how-can-i-read-skype-log-files-chatsync/868096)
- [How do I export the history of Skype?](https://superuser.com/questions/67133/how-do-i-export-the-history-of-skype)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925080/is-there-a-way-to-access-skype-im-logs